# where is my uploaded facebook open graph object link

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ipad, facebook-graph-api

In the most recent iOS SDk 3.5 they allow users to upload object directly to facebook (which is outlined [here](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/change-log-3.x/)). I have the following code which executes successfully and I am able to get the object id. However I need the full URL of where this object is at. Where do I get the URL from the generated object id?

```
 [FBRequestConnection startForPostOpenGraphObject:object
               completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                   if(error) {
                       NSLog(@"Error in posting open graph Object: %@", error);
                   } else {


                   }
               }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Facebook graph objects can be accessed via the graph API directly at the url https://graph.facebook.com/(object_id)

Note that if the resource requires an access token, you have to access via https and pass the access token - standard GET stuff:

https://graph.facebook.com/(object_id)?access_token=(access_token)